# Apache Benchmark and Codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, benchmarking

When using something like:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/ci
```

I get about 380 requests/sec.

When using:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/ci/
```

I get about 12 requests/sec.

What's going on?

Edit:  Tried HttpFox for Firefox and what I see is that when putting localhost/ci it shows a 301 redirect to localhost/ci/

Answer (score 0):

Is there an .htaccess file in the ci/ folder, or in one of its  subfolders? Are there rewrite rules?

Maybe the rewrite rules do the matching differently for /ci/ and /ci which results in more work at the webserver level.

Can you post a "tree" (linux command) of your current working directory?

Comment: I'm on windows using xampp. I have an .htaccess file in the ci folder.
I tried without the .htaccess and the result is the same

Comment: Did some more tests with other apps and it happens with all so i guess that's nothing to do with ci.
Can anyone tell me where i can look to fix this?

Comment: @JEagle - There may other `.htaccess` files located "further up" in the directory structure. You could also use something like HttpFox for Firefox to see if/how the server is redirecting those links.